# How useful is Sass's extend-feature?

Tags: css

I'm have currently started to learn Sass.

Now, looking on the way 'extend' is explained in the Basics documentation (http://sass-lang.com/guide) and wondering if it is really useful.

I mean: This ...

```
.message {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #333;
}

.success {
  @extend .message;
  border-color: green;
}

.error {
  @extend .message;
  border-color: red;
}

.warning {
  @extend .message;
  border-color: yellow;
}
```

... compiles to ...

```
.message, .success, .error, .warning {
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #333;
}

.success {
  border-color: green;
}

.error {
  border-color: red;
}

.warning {
  border-color: yellow;
}
```

I could accomplish the same if I add the class **.message** to every HTML-element to which I want to apply this styles.

It's no work saved if I write multiple times @extend .message compared to multiple times class="message".

**Right?**

Or is there something else which I haven't understood?

*Then please correct me.*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP does not need any help

Comment: Yes, everything you can do with SASS (or any other CSS preprocessor) can be done with plain CSS. As about the example, it's normal that documentation covers simple cases.

Comment: @Justinas I need help in so far that I need to know if I should use for my stylesheets or not. Perhaps someone asks me later why and then I have to answer.

Comment: @st88 It will generate valid/pure CSS. It's code reuse example. And yes, you can use it in your styleheets pre-processor files

Comment: Consider many cases that you don't or can't change HTML or do not want to put classes on every element. For example instead of using a class called `.list-standard` to remove default `padding` of lists, you can easilly @extend it. And note that most of the times `@extend` is used to share and reuse a piece of code called `%placeholders%`.